# How can I add more file types to Archive Manager?

Tags: plugins, archive

I want to make a plugin or something that can extract a [PFS0](https://switchbrew.org/wiki/NCA_Format#PFS0) file because it's a simple format  and I want something to do, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Sorry.
I do not know any utility to handle those encrypted files of Nintendo, and less some plugins.

Comment: "Archive Manager" aka `file-roller` the "archive manager for GNOME" has a homepage or two: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/FileRoller, and http://fileroller.sourceforge.net/  from a breif glance, if you had an existing program it could be integrated into their code repository https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/file-roller/tree/master/src however, beware that license complications might prevent it from being accepted. I would encourage you to author the plugin as a standalone program, and when stable approach the file-roller author(s) about inclusion, or even reach out to them now about the prospect :)

Comment: A PFS0 isn't encrypted, so that won't be an issue.